# End date of role in Teradata

Tags: teradata, role

I need to know end date of role in Teradata. I know how I get create date

```
select * from dbc.rolemembers a 
join dbc.allrights b
a.rolename=b.rolename
```

But I can't find where is the end of role. In Teradata Administrator I can't find it too. Please, can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: What is an *end date of role*? When a role is dropped all rights assgined to it are revoked, too.

Comment: yes, when the role will be dropped. I understand, that after dropping the role with their all rights can't be in database, but before dropping can I know when this role will be dropped? How long some role will be active?

Comment: A role is active when it's set via `set role abc` or `set role all`. There's no *expiry date* for any table/view/role/etc. it expires when a DBA subits the `DROP` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to explain is an audit process for the creation of a role, the rights it was assigned and to whom the role was assigned. That is above and beyond the DCL statements to `CREATE {role}`, `GRANT {access} TO {role}`, `REVOKE {access} FROM {role}`, `GRANT {role} TO {member}`, `REVOKE {role} FROM {member}`, `DROP {role}`. It also falls outside the scope of Teradata Administrator or Teradata Studio to track that information.

If you have a security requirement that stipulates you need to track this level of detail, you can either piece it together from sufficient DBQL history or you can create a set of stored procedures that are used by your Security Administrator and/or DBA team to administer role based privileges and user administration.

Beyond that, you can also use Access Logging to track the successful or denied execution of CREATE/DROP USER, CREATE/DROP ROLE, and GRANT statements that are run outside the context of the stored procedures you have put in place to audit the administration of privileges in your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)